# Set a task priority or disable a task run, when resources are low

Tags: android, performance, timertask

I am running a background timer task that does a bit of computational work every hour. My question is if I can somehow set the task to run in a lower priority than the others. Alternatively, it would be OK to skip the run of the task if resources are low (say, memory is below 50%, battery is below 30%, and CPU is above 60%). It's not mandatory to compute every time, as long as I get a steady run.

Can you suggest me a way to do this? I really don't want to have my app mess up with the user's experience, especially when users are playing a game, listening to music, watching a movie etc.

Comment: There is no such mechanism readily provided by Android. You need to add intent receiver to check battery state, memory state etc. And according you can kill your task. I think that will take more resources than your bit of computation work.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to conserve resources:

1. Do your work in an extra thread on which you call [`setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) after creating it. This way your thread will be scheduled with the lowest priority. Wake this thread up every hour.
2. Consider waking up your app to do work using [`AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). This conserves energy because the *"system can adjust alarms' delivery times to cause them to fire simultaneously, avoiding waking the device from sleep more than necessary."*
3. You can use [`ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMyMemoryState%28android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo%29) to figure out if system memory is tight. If the field [`lastTrimLevel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#lastTrimLevel) of the [`ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#lastTrimLevel) object filled by this call is [`TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL) or [`TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW) you should skip running your task.